# import ionic3 font in variables

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

inside the file variables.scss of the ionic3 project it does the import of two fonts: roboto and noto-sans as follows:

```
@import "roboto";
@import "noto-sans";
```

Where do these fonts come from? How to import raleway font? I have tried to put this line and it does not work:

```
@import "raleway";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just checked my `node_modules` and the `roboto` and `noto-sans` fonts are stored in `node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/`

If you want to use the `raleway` font, you should be in possession of the `.ttf`, `.woff`, and `.woff2` files. If you only have the `.ttf` font, check out [FontSquirrel's font files generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Location: `src/assets/fonts/Raleway.ttf` etc.

Then you can create your font (`app.component.scss` or `variables.scss`)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Raleway.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Raleway.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Raleway.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

Now you can use your font:

```
p { font-family: "Raleway" !important; }
```

Or change the default font of your ionic app (`variables.scss`)

```
$font-family-md-base: "Raleway";
$font-family-ios-base: "Raleway";
$font-family-wp-base: "Raleway";
```

[Answer Credit](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-fonts-in-ionic3/87048/12)